# how to create an interactive menu in C that moves from one function into another without redrawing the menu

Tags: c

My goal is to produce a program that will take a file as input and "encode" the text within by shifting the characters ahead 3 (so 'a' would be come 'd').  It should produce an output file with the encoded text.  The menu is to take user input and execute the function that is assigned to the number selected.

I'm early on at creating this program, but running short on time and am struggling with how to structure it.  Currently, I have the menu displaying, but when a sub function is called, it displays but then the menu overwrites it and I can't figure out why.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the code I have so far...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define INPUT_FILE 1    //define statements
#define OUTPUT_FILE 2
#define NUM_TO_SHIFT 3
#define ENCODE 4
#define QUIT 0

int menu();     //function prototypes
int input();
int output();
int shift();
int encode();
void quit();

int main()
{
    int choice;     // main variables
    char user_filename[100];

    choice = menu();   // get user's first selection

    while(choice != QUIT)   //execute so long as choice is not equal to QUIT
    {
        switch(choice)
            {
                case INPUT_FILE:
                    printf("Enter the filename of the file to encode:\n");
                    printf("(hit the Enter key when done)\n");
                    gets(user_filename);
                    break;
                case OUTPUT_FILE: output();
                    break;
                case NUM_TO_SHIFT: shift();
                    break;
                case ENCODE: encode();
                    break;
                case QUIT: quit();
                    break;
                default:    printf("Oops! An invalid choice slipped through. ");
                            printf("Please try again.\n");
            }
      choice = menu(); /* get user's subsequent selections */
   }

   printf("Bye bye!\n");
   return 0;
}

int menu(void)
{
    int option;

    printf("Text Encoder Service\n\n");
    printf("1.\tEnter name of input file (currently 'Secret.txt')\n");
    printf("2.\tEnter name of output file (currently not set)\n");
    printf("3.\tEnter number of characters data should be shifted (currently +7)\n");
    printf("4.\tEncode the text\n\n");
    printf("0.\tQuit\n\n");
    printf("Make your selection: ");

    while( (scanf(" %d", &option) != 1) /* non-numeric input */
          || (option < 0)               /* number too small */
          || (option > 4))              /* number too large */
    {
      fflush(stdin);                    /* clear bad data from buffer */
      printf("That selection isn't valid. Please try again.\n\n");
      printf("Your choice? ");
    }
    return option;
}

int input()
{

}

int output()
{
    return 2;
}

int shift()
{
    return 3;
}

int encode()
{
    return 4;
}

void quit()
{
    printf("Quiting...Bye!");
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `gets(user_filename)` to get the file name since `gets()` reads up to a `\n` and stops reading. Your `scanf` for the menu option does not read the `\n` at the end of the line when the user types in the menu option. Essentially, you're making `gets` read a string without words in it. The line you *want* to read is actually the next line. Using `scanf` instead of `gets` will fix it.

Otherwise, your program is working as expected - it's just that your functions don't do anything yet that your menu is "overwriting" the submenus. See http://ideone.com/F2pEs for an implementation with `scanf` instead of `gets`.

Comment: Thanks, this sheds some light on what is happening and how to solve it.  I've implemented and am feeling more confident in it now.

Answer (score 0):

use getchar(); soon after the gets(user_filename); it will wait to get the character

```
 gets(user_filename);
 getchar();
 break;
```

Comment: Again, good info to have.  You guys are all teaching me things I might have taken a while to figure out!

Answer (score 0):

[As in this question which Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836509/c-function-exiting-before-input?rq=1) has highlighted as a match, you need to clear out the buffer to remove the newline that's waiting in there.

Add this code after reading a valid menu option:

```
do
{
    c = getchar();
} while (c != EOF && c != '\n');
```

where `c` is a `char` declared up by `option`. This loops over remaining characters in the input stream until `EOF` (End Of File) or a newline character is reached, meaning they don't affect your call to `gets()`. Note that `gets()` is considered insecure because it doesn't protect against buffer overflow, a user could easily enter more than 100 characters (inc. newline) and start writing into memory that shouldn't be touched by their input. You would do well to lookup the secure equivalent when you see compiler warnings around function calls like this, typically they take a second parameter which is the maximum size of the buffer being read into.

Comment: All good info.  All I can say is that I'm still learning this language but this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this answer is way late but having come across it, I can't help but write something.
Let's get straight to it. You will have an array of menus, with the array elements being the options you want in your menu. Then while in a truthy condition, loop through the elements of the array, selecting the option you want.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
//function prototypes
int input();
int output();
int shift();
int encode();
void quit();
int main(){
int menus_on = 1;
  const char *menus[5] = {"Input","Output","Shift","Encode","Quit"};
  while(menus_on){
    int menu,*temp;

    for(int i =0;i<6;i++){
      printf("%d: %s\n",i,menus[i]);
    }
      printf("Select menu\n");
      scanf("%d",temp);
      menu = *temp;
      printf("Selected menu::%d\n",menu);
      switch(menu){
        case 0:
        input();
        break;
        case 1:
        output();
        break;
        case 2:
        shift();
        break;
        case 3:
        encode();
        break;
        case 4:
        quit();
        break;
        default:
        printf("Invalid selection\n");
        break;
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
int input() {
return 0;
}
int encode () {
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just did it. Thanks a lot Fabio Turati