# How can I create a menu in C?

Tags: c

Make a menu with the following options.

A) Generate an array of integers n elements.

B) Change element values ​​by position

C) Show the number of values ​​that are repeated within the element, ie if we have an array with the following values ​​2,3,5,2,6,5,7, 
They must show that 2 was presented twice, 3 once 5 twice, 6 and 7 once again

D) Exit the program.

I´m a student and I don´t know my code would be with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ingreso(){
    int i=0,tamano,matriz[i],d,a=0;

printf("Escriba el numero de elementos que quieres ingresar "); 
scanf("%d", &tamano);
printf("\n");   

for(d=1;d <=tamano; d++) 
{ 

printf("Escriba un numero de la matriz "); 
scanf("%i", &matriz[i]); 

if(i=2){
a=a+1;
printf("\n Se repitio:%d veces \n\n", a);   
}


}
printf("%d", matriz[i]);




}



int main (){

    printf("Ingresa los valores que tu quieras \n");
    printf("Ingresa un numero negativo cuando desies salir \n\n");
    ingreso();      
    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945486/how-to-create-an-interactive-menu-in-c-that-moves-from-one-function-into-another

Comment: See http://www.tenouk.com/cpluscodesnippet/dowhilemenu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you the pseudo code:

```
   1: input n numbers using scanf() 
   2:sort the array using any sort algorithm.
   3:once it is sorted you can easily count if( a[i]==a[i+1])
   4: print count and a[i]
```

Or

```
  1:input n numbers using scanf() 
  2: for i=0 till n-1{
  3:      for j=i+1 till n{
  4:          if a[i] equal to a[j]
                    if(prev_read[j-1]==i)
                      ignore and break
                    prev_read[j-1]==i
  5:                count++
  6:          else
                    prev_read[j-1]=-1
  7:                count =1
           }
  8:      print a[i] and count
      }
```

I think this should solve your problem. I hope you are not looking into optimization now so this could be a solution. You will face some errors for sure.I did not test this. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks :) i will use it